# showModaDdialog in Google addons is slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Currently calling **showModalDialog()** in a Google docs addon will take *3 seconds* to display a modal popup. Sometimes it is much more : 6 seconds.

This is a minimum : a blank popup will take - at least - 3 seconds, a real popup will take even more.

On the contrary, when a user opens a popup in Google docs, like 'insert special character', it is very fast (less than 1 second, almost instant).

Is there a way to avoid this very slow API response time ?

Comment: Google API is very slow, but that seems extra slow for a blank Dialog.   1. Are you opening as an html template? 2. when you run the debugger is there anything indicating why it might be slow.

Comment: I open the popup with this javascript function :

`function openInsertTab(width, height){  
  docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('insert_tab').evaluate();  
html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(width).setHeight(height);  
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, ' ');  
}`

If I try to debug this function, I have an error for the line with setSandboxMode :
_Cannot find method setWidth((class)). (line 262, file "utils")_

Comment: make sure that width and height are numbers.

Comment: I hard coded the height and width in the method. Now the popup opens. In the execution transcript I see very short execution times :[15-11-30 16:16:54:524 CET] Starting execution
[15-11-30 16:16:54:536 CET] Execution succeeded [0 seconds total runtime] ---> 12ms
Whereas as a user I see that the popup shows after more than 1 second